# How can I calculate the gradients of my outputs in respect to certain input values of my Tensor with Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gradient, tensor, pde

I am trying to implement a Physics induced neural network, inspiration drawn from [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-differential-equations-with-neural-networks-afdcf7b8bcc4) but my partial differential equations require a bit more complexity since I use multiple variables in my input tensor and need to calculate different derivatives for these variables to use in my equations.

My input tensors I called pde_samples and boundary_samples for the different equations all have shape `torch.Size([22929, 3])` where the first column is `t`, the second `x` and the third `y`.

These are the sampling functions I wrote and will use later on.

```
#imports
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchopt

from functorch import make_functional, grad, vmap

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X_BOUNDARY = 82
Y_BOUNDARY = 77
T_END = 22929

def pde_sampling(n = 1000):
    samples = pd.DataFrame(columns=['t', 'x', 'y'])

    # sample n points
    for i in range(n):
        sample = np.array([])

        # sample the boundary points
        x_sample = np.random.randint(1, X_BOUNDARY - 1)
        y_sample = np.random.randint(1, Y_BOUNDARY - 1)
        t_sample = np.random.randint(0, T_END)

        sample = np.append(sample, [t_sample, x_sample, y_sample])

        # add the sample to the samples array
        samples.loc[i] = sample

    return torch.tensor(samples.values, dtype=torch.float32)

def boundary_sampling(n = 1000):
    boundaries_samples = []
    
    # sample n points
    for boundary in ['left', 'right', 'bottom', 'top']:
        samples = pd.DataFrame(columns=['t', 'x', 'y'])
        for i in range(int(n/4)):
            sample = np.array([])

            # sample the boundary points
            x_sample = np.random.randint(0, X_BOUNDARY)
            y_sample = np.random.randint(0, Y_BOUNDARY)
            t_sample = np.random.randint(0, T_END)

            if boundary == 'left':
                x_sample = 0
                k = 0
            elif boundary == 'right':
                x_sample = X_BOUNDARY
                k = n/len(boundaries)
            elif boundary == 'bottom':
                y_sample = 0
                k = n/len(boundaries)*2
            elif boundary == 'top':
                y_sample = Y_BOUNDARY
                k = n/len(boundaries)*3
            sample = np.append(sample, [t_sample, x_sample, y_sample])

            # add the sample to the samples array
            samples.loc[i+k] = sample

        boundaries_samples.append(torch.tensor(samples.values, dtype=torch.float32))
    return boundaries_samples
```

My output tensor has shape `torch.Size([22929, 1])` where the output value is temperature `u`.

This is the neural network I am using.

```
class NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        input_size: int = 1,
        output_size: int = 1,
        dim_hidden: int = 1,
        act: nn.Module = nn.ReLU(),
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_size, dim_hidden),
            act,
            nn.Linear(dim_hidden, dim_hidden),
            act,
            nn.Linear(dim_hidden, output_size)
        )

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.model(x)
```

Here I make use of functorch to make the model functional as to be able to calculate the gradients.

```
# create the PINN model and make it functional using functorch utilities
model = NN(input_size=3, output_size=1, dim_hidden=64)
fmodel, params = make_functional(model)

def u(input: torch.Tensor, params: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    # only a single element is supported thus unsqueeze must be applied
    # for batching multiple inputs, `vmap` must be used as below
    input_ = input.unsqueeze(0)
    u_pred = fmodel(params, input_).squeeze(0)
    return u_pred

# use `vmap` primitive to allow efficient batching of the input
u_vmap = vmap(u, in_dims=(0, None))

# return function for computing higher order gradients with respect
# to input by simply composing `grad` calls and use again `vmap` for
# efficient batching of the input

# first order derivative with respect to t, the first column of input
dudt = vmap(grad(u, argnums=0), in_dims=(0, None))
# first order derivative with respect to x, the second column of input
dudx = vmap(grad(u, argnums=1), in_dims=(0, None))
dudxdx = vmap(grad(grad(u, argnums=1), argnums=1), in_dims=(0, None))
# first order derivative with respect to y, the third column of input
dudy = vmap(grad(u, argnums=2), in_dims=(0, None))
dudydy = vmap(grad(grad(u, argnums=2), argnums=2), in_dims=(0, None))
```

Here I then define the loss functions and train the model.

```
C = 1
def loss_pde(input: torch.Tensor, params: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    loss = nn.MSELoss()
    interior = dudt(input, params) - (C**2) * (dudxdx(input, params) + dudydy(input, params))

    return loss(interior, torch.zeros_like(interior))

def loss_boundary_x(input: torch.Tensor, params: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    loss = nn.MSELoss()
    boundary = dudx(input, params)
    return loss(boundary, torch.zeros_like(boundary))

def loss_boundary_y(input: torch.Tensor, params: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    loss = nn.MSELoss()
    boundary = dudy(input, params)
    return loss(boundary, torch.zeros_like(boundary))

# choose the configuration
batch_size = 100
num_iter = 1000  # maximum number of iterations
learning_rate = 0.01  # learning rate

# choose optimizer with functional API using functorch
optimizer = torchopt.FuncOptimizer(torchopt.adam(lr=learning_rate))

# train the model
losses = []
for i in range(num_iter):
    # sample the PDE and boundary points
    pde_samples = pde_sampling(n=batch_size)
    boundary_samples = boundary_sampling(n=batch_size)

    #compute the loss from PDE
    pde_loss = loss_pde(pde_samples, params)

    # compute the loss from boundary conditions
    boundary_loss_x0 = loss_boundary_x(boundary_samples[0], params)
    boundary_loss_x1 = loss_boundary_x(boundary_samples[1], params)
    boundary_loss_y0 = loss_boundary_y(boundary_samples[2], params)
    boundary_loss_y1 = loss_boundary_y(boundary_samples[3], params)
    boundary_loss = boundary_loss_x0 + boundary_loss_x1 + boundary_loss_y0 + boundary_loss_y1

    # update the parameters using the functional API
    loss = boundary_loss + pde_loss
    params = optimizer.step(loss, params)

    # store the loss
    losses.append(loss.item())
    if i % 100 == 0:    
        print(f"Iteration {i} with loss {float(loss)}")
```

Resulting in the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     19 
     20     #compute the loss from PDE
---> 21     pde_loss = loss_pde(pde_samples, params)
     22 
     23     # compute the loss from boundary conditions

 in loss_pde(input, params)
      2 def loss_pde(input: torch.Tensor, params: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
      3     loss = nn.MSELoss()
----> 4     interior = dudt(input, params) - (C**2) * (dudxdx(input, params) + dudydy(input, params))
      5 
      6     return loss(interior, torch.zeros_like(interior))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_functorch/vmap.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    432 
    433         # If chunk_size is not specified.
--> 434         return _flat_vmap(
    435             func, batch_size, flat_in_dims, flat_args, args_spec, out_dims, randomness, **kwargs
    436         )

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_functorch/vmap.py in fn(*args, **kwargs)
     37     def fn(*args, **kwargs):
...
-> 1258                     raise RuntimeError('grad_and_value(f)(*args): Expected f(*args) '
   1259                                        'to return a scalar Tensor, got tensor with '
   1260                                        f'{output.dim()} dims. Maybe you wanted to '

RuntimeError: grad_and_value(f)(*args): Expected f(*args) to return a scalar Tensor, got tensor with 1 dims. Maybe you wanted to use the vjp or jacrev APIs instead?
```

I am not familiar with vjp or jacrev APIs and do not really know what is going wrong and how I can fix it. I tried switching to torch.autograd.grad but this seemed to not work that very well with the functional approach to differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Edit: This answer isn't working. Please flag for deletion or lmk if solved, keeping answer for now so that the asker's error can remain displayed in the comments. -Brock</sup>

A scalar tensor in PyTorch is a tensor with one element, but it is not equivalent to a one-dimensional tensor with one element. You might want to try converting to a scalar with `some_tensor.item()`.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html

Comment: Sadly vmap prevents this. `RuntimeError: vmap: It looks like you're either (1) calling .item() on a Tensor or (2) attempting to use a Tensor in some data-dependent control flow or (3) encountering this error in PyTorch internals. For (1): we don't support vmap over calling .item() on a Tensor, please try to rewrite what you're doing with other operations. For (2): If you're doing some control flow instead, we don't support that yet, please shout over at https://github.com/pytorch/functorch/issues/257 . For (3): please file an issue.`